# create general function in cakephp 3.4

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I want to show some social links dynamically in the website header. That's why I write a function in the model(SociallinksTable.php)

```
public function getscoial()
{
    $this->Sociallinks->find('all', [ 'conditions' => ['satatus' =>1]]);

    return $socials;
}
```

Next I call the function in beforeFilter under AppController.php

```
$socials = $this->Sociallinks->getscoial();
$this->set('socials', $socials);
```

But I can't access the variable in front_header.ctp which is located in src\Template\Element. Is it a wrong procedure or I'm missing something. Please suggest.

Comment: in your view, when you are using the element, you have to pass the variable to that element. Also: consider using a cell

Comment: yes, I am using $socials variable in the view page.

Comment: but are you passing that variable to the element? see the [**manual**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html#passing-variables-into-an-element)

Comment: How to pass the variable in the element?

Comment: did you take a look at the manual? `$this->element('front_header', [
    "socials" => $socials
]);`

Comment: Yes. I tried that but it's not passing the variable. Have I placed the function correctly?

Comment: I see many typos (`getscoial`, `satatus`...). Maybe it's worth take a look at them

Comment: I corrected the typos but still the same situation.

Comment: what do you see when you debug($socials) in the view page? And if you do the same in the front_header element?

Comment: It's showing Notice (8): Undefined variable: socials [APP/Template\Element\front_header.ctp, line 13]

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got my answer. I need to call the function in App controller

```
public function initialize()
{
       $Sociallinks = TableRegistry::get('sociallinks');
       $query = $Sociallinks->find('all',['conditions'=>['status'=>1]]);
       $this->set('slinks',$query);
}
```

Now I can use $slinks in header and footer from any any controller and any action. Also I have define `use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;` top of the App controller.